# expand.js - collapsing when expanding another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i found the neat little plugin which make a cool expand/collaps-thingy on my site. 
The problem is that i only want one 'div' open at the time - i just can't figure out what to call, and where?

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wLEGS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to trigger the toggle event? They are calling it on their `h2.expand` - you would do something similar but with the element you want.

```
$(function () {
    $("h2.expand").toggler();
});
```

**Edit**

The current plugin does not have the functionality that you are looking for. [jQuery accordian](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) does.

Comment: That line is just for initializing the expand.js-script. The function i need to call is the actual "close open divs"-function.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I'll let it roll for an hour or so, or else i'll accept your answer.